# Attaching data to document node outside of document ready

Tags: jquery

I have data in cookies that I want to use for pre-loading images.  While the page is loaded, I keep the info in arrays.  I plan to attach the information to a node.  I am thinking the $(document) node since I believe it should exist but I'm not sure.  My question is:

Is it safe to use `$('document').data('key',value)` outside of the `ready()` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use any jquery code outside ready(), ready is just to delay your code execution till all html loaded.